# SAS Enterprise Guide - Get Code from Process flow

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I was wondering if there is a easy and fast way to get the code from the programs that I have created in SAS Enterprise Guides process flow?

I am creating the program in SAS Enterprise Guide, and then creating a script for later usage in SAS, as I am not strong enough to program it from scratch.

At the moment, I am opening each step and copying the code, but there must be a faster way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an option in the File menu:

```
File -> Export -> Export all Code in Process Flow
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been updated instead of *File* -> *Export* -> *Export all Code in Process Flow*.

You can find this under the *Share* button in the *Process Flow* tab.
*Share* -> *Export all Code in Process Flow*

[image: Share button location]

Answer (score 1):

If you rename the file from an EGP to a .zip and then open the file you'll see you have folders relating to objects in the EG project.

You can then pull extract these pieces of SAS code and rename as necessary.

I've also seen some software which can examine EGP files if you do a search.